HTMX batch updates in a counter
I was wondering whether it's possible in htmx to somehow batch request data & only send one request after debounce/throttle period, using no client-side JavaScript.
For example, assuming I have the following simple counter (in JSX template form since I'm using Bun + Elysia):
function Counter() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button hx-post="/increment" hx-target="#count">
        -
      </button>
      <div id="count">{count}</div>
      <button hx-post="/decrement" hx-target="#count">
        +
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

Is there any way to change the increment/decrement logic, such that, e.g., I can batch any clicks that occur within a 300 ms time window and send a request to update with the difference, e.g. something like hx-post={`/update:${inc - dec}`} ?

For delayed deboucing you can use the trigger modifier.
hx-trigger="click delay:500ms"

I'm not sure how do you handle the post data within react component, but here's a working example using htmx + hyperscript, which sends the sum of the two values, maybe it will give you a general idea on how to do similar thing in react:
<form hx-post="/calculate" hx-trigger="click delay:500ms" hx-target="#count">
    <input type="hidden" name="counter" id="counter" value="0">
    <button type="submit" name="decrement" _="on click decrement #counter's @value">
        -
    </button>
    <div id="count"></div>
    <button type="submit" name="increment" _="on click increment #counter's @value">
        +
    </button>
</form>

Notice I've added hidden field and set the button type to submit, to make it easier for htmx to get the post value when data is submitted via button click.

Unfortunately, without using client-side JavaScript, it's not possible to batch requests or implement debounce/throttle logic. The reason is that HTML and server-side languages like Node.js don't have the ability to control user interactions in the browser in real-time. They can only respond to requests that have been sent to the server.
The functionality you're describing requires real-time control over user interactions, which can only be achieved with client-side JavaScript. You would need to use JavaScript to listen for button clicks, start a timer when the first click is detected, and then send a request to the server with the total count of clicks when the timer expires.
Here's a basic example of how you could implement this with JavaScript:
import { useState } from 'react';

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  let timer = null;

  const handleClick = (increment) => {
    setCount(count + increment);

    if (timer !== null) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      fetch(`/update${count}`, { method: 'POST' });
      timer = null;
    }, 300);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick(-1)}>
        -
      </button>
      <div id="count">{count}</div>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick(1)}>
        +
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}


Hi, sorry I wasn't clear, I'm using HTMX, which does allow for debounce/throttle behaviour, however, what I'm wondering about is whether it can be used to batch request data somehow
